# How to add labels to nodes in a graph in networkx?

Tags: python, integer, partitioning, networkx

I am writing a code for integer partition and constructing a graph where each node is a partition. I would like to label the nodes in the graph with partition elements like {2,1,1}, {1,1,1,1},{2,2} etc.

So I want to know, how to label a node in networkx.

I have already seen the code for labeling node but I didn't get it.
The code is given below:

```
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,
                       nodelist=[0,1,2,3],
                       node_color='r',
                       node_size=500,
                    alpha=0.8)
```

But what I want is to label individual nodes of already constructed graph!

I am providing my code here, so that you can have better understanding of it.

```
import networkx as nx
from matplotlib import pylab as pl

def partitions(num):
    final=[[num]]

    for i in range(1,num):
        a=num-i
        res=partitions(i)
        for ele in res:
            if ele[0]<=a:
                final.append([a]+ele)

    return final

def drawgraph(parlist):
    #This is to draw the graph
    G=nx.Graph()
    length=len(parlist)
    print "length is %s\n" % length

    node_list=[]

    for i in range(1,length+1):
        node_list.append(i)

    G.add_cycle(node_list)

    nx.draw_circular(G)
    pl.show()
```

Please help me.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your `node_list` was composed of integers, your nodes got the string representation of those integers as labels. But your nodes can be any hashable object, not just integers. So the simplest thing to do would be to make your `node_list` the string representation of the items in `parlist`. (The items in `parlist` are lists, which are mutable and therefore not hashable. That's why we can't just use `parlist` as our `node_list`.)

There is also the function [nx.relabel_nodes](http://networkx.lanl.gov/archive/networkx-1.5/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.relabel_nodes.html), which we could use instead, but I think just giving the nodes the right label in the first place is simpler.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def partitions(num):
    final = [[num]]

    for i in range(1, num):
        a = num - i
        res = partitions(i)
        for ele in res:
            if ele[0] <= a:
                final.append([a] + ele)

    return final


def drawgraph(parlist):
    G = nx.Graph()
    length = len(parlist)
    print "length is %s\n" % length
    node_list = [str(item) for item in parlist]
    G.add_cycle(node_list)
    pos = nx.circular_layout(G)
    draw_lifted(G, pos)


def draw_lifted(G, pos=None, offset=0.07, fontsize=16):
    """Draw with lifted labels
    http://networkx.lanl.gov/examples/advanced/heavy_metal_umlaut.html
    """
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G) if pos is None else pos
    nx.draw(G, pos, font_size=fontsize, with_labels=False)
    for p in pos:  # raise text positions
        pos[p][1] += offset
    nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
    plt.show()

drawgraph(partitions(4))
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Thank you for replying. I got the answer and now, I have to **understand** your code. But here, each node should have only two edges, but in your code, more than one two edges are present for each node. Can we overcome that? Because it's looking like a very complicated web. If it's not possible, no problem. Once again thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you please tell me where some more information (like documentation, examples etc.) will be there on this topic which are easier to understand, so that I will go and search there instead of troubling you?

Comment: The best resources I know of is the [official docs](http://networkx.lanl.gov) and [the gallery](http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/gallery.html) for examples.

Comment: Can we implement Test Driven Development in this? If yes, how can we do that? Can you please give some examples. I tried to understand TDD, but I didn't find much information in the net or I didn't come across suitable required information. I know a little bit of basics, that's all. Please help me in this. Thank you!